# if $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group of order $p^n$, where $p$ is prime and $n \geq 1$, prove that $G$ must have a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: what topics have you covered in group theory?

Comment: Have you heard about the Cauchy theorem?

Comment: The title is not explanatory. Also don't write the corpus in bold. Please edit.

Comment: or Sylow's thm?

Comment: Cauchy and Sylow: Too hard for this simple problem ... you can solve it directly.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $G$ has order $p^n$, what can be the order of an element of $G$?

Comment: Does this say about existence of element of order $p$??

Comment: oh i would have to use induction.. i was overlooking that.. it is fine now!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use induction and the fact that the centre of $G$ is non-trivial.